# How to send User credentials from zuul to microservice module in Spring Boot Microservices

Tags: java, spring, security, jwt, microservices

I have three microservices module auth-server, zuul-server and product-server. I want to send user credentials that is authorised from auth-server from zuul-server to product-server and obtain it in proudct-server ?

I have tried to set token in zuul server header and get it from product-server. But i obtain null in product-server.

```
if (username != null) { 
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<String> authorities = (List<String>) claims.get("authorities"); 
   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( username, null, authorities.stream().map( SimpleGrantedAuthority::new ).collect(Collectors.toList()));
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
}
```

I want this securitycontext to another microservice module so can i can get user credentials from it.

Comment: Please provide code examples.

Comment: if (username != null) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<String> authorities = (List<String>) claims.get("authorities");
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                username,
                                null, authorities.stream().map(
                                SimpleGrantedAuthority::new
                        ).collect(Collectors.toList()));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

Comment: I want this securitycontext to another microservice module so can i can get user credentials from it.